# cy.intercept is not a function Cypress test

Tags: testing, cypress

I am copying code from the Cypress docs and have returned this error
`cy.intercept is not a function`

[image]

My code is straight from the docs...

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Visit Home Page', () => {
      cy.intercept('search/*', [{ item: 'Book 1' }, { item: 'Book 2' }]).as('getSearch')
  }
})
```

Not sure why this would happen?

Comment: What is the cypress version installed on your system?

Comment: `"cypress": "^5.3.0",`

Comment: You have to upgrade to v6.0 for `cy.intercept()` to work.

Comment: Did it solve the issue for you ?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [intercept - history](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#History), the functionality has been available since **Cypress v5.1.0**, it was just called `cy.route2()` (in case you did not want to upgrade).

> Version  Changes
> 6.0.0   Renamed cy.route2() to cy.intercept().
> 6.0.0   Removed experimentalNetworkStubbing option and made it the default behavior.
> 5.1.0   Added experimental cy.route2() command under experimentalNetworkStubbing option.

But if you remain at v5.3.0, you will have to add

```
"experimentalNetworkStubbing": true
```

to cypress.json.

---

**Version 7.0.0**

Release notes say

> cy.route2() was previously aliased to cy.intercept(). Now the alias cy.route2() has been removed. Please update usage of cy.route2() to cy.intercept()