# Why do I get cy.intercept is not a function?

Tags: vue.js, http, axios, mocking, cypress

I am trying to intercept a POST request but I'm getting the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3leQ.png)

This is my test file code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWOBH.png)

I've found a similar question:

[cy.intercept is not a function Cypress test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65043143/17204560)

That question was solved by upgrading the cypress version above v5.3. But I already have cypress version 6.14.15. The error is seemingly only replicating on the `.Then()` part, which is weird because the cy.intercept function is called in the previous line of code and NOT in the `.Then()` part. where is the problem exactly?

EDIT:
here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test-project-v2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {},
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `package.json` file to check the Cypress's version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Manuel Abascal I just shared the package.json file. I haven't tried the answer yet  but I'll let you know today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the assertion of the `cy.intercept` route like so instead:

```js
cy.wait('@dialog').should(response => {
    expect(response.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
});
```

You also have a typo in this code snippet in `respose.body`:

```js
cy.wait('@dialog').its('respose.body').should('have.Congrats');
```

I would also check your `package.json` & your current `Cypress`'s version installed. Note that `cy.intercept()` was introduced in [`Cypress 6.0.0`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#6-0-1).

Comment: Hello, I tried your response and it works, but it does not really answer my question. I want to stub a POST request using cy.intercept. but the moment I write that line (or literally any line from the actual documentation examples) it tells me the same error:
cy.intercept is not a function...

Cypress version: 6.14.15

Comment: The problem was the cypress version being used was 3. but when running npm cypress --version, I got 6. when I re-installed cypress it solved the problem. Thank you! @Manuel